# Using openSession() and getCurrentSession() together

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am new to hibernate and below is my use case.

```java
@EnableTransactionManagement
class A{

   @Autowired
   SessionFactory sessionFactory;

   @Transactional
   public void getProducts(String id) {
      List<Products> products = sessionFactory.openSession().fetch(id);
      getProductsDetials(products);
   }

   @Transactional
   public List<String> getProductsDetails(List<Products> products) {
      List<String> productName = new ArrayList();
      for(Products product : products) {
         roductName.add(sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().fetch(product.getId()));
      }
   }
}
```

I'm getting below exception when trying to fetch product name in `getProductsDetails` from db:

```
or.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException : could not prepare statement.
```

Please help me out.

Comment: Don't use `openSession` as that opens a new session outside the scope of spring and eventually your application will die due to all connections to the database being used. I also don't get your usecase, you already have the products and try to load them again? Your code would probably not even compile.

Comment: This is just a sample use case. Somehow the session provided by openSEssion is not available when i am doing getCurrentSession() if that is the case? @M.Deinum

Comment: Doesn't matter if it is a sample the `openSession` opens always a new session and will leak a connection and session if not properly handled. You basically ignore the `@Transacgtional` gotten session here, so you end up with 2 session 1 managed and 1 unmanaged (which will eventually lead to all sorts of issues). So never use `openSession` when using `@Transactional`.